# How to multiply numbers in Swift?

Tags: swift, floating-point, calculator

I am working on a calculator in Swift, but I have a small problem:
when multiplying two numbers, I don't have the same results as a regular calculator.

For example:

In Swift :

```
0.333328247070312 * 16 = 5.33325195312499
```

In a regular calculator:

```
0.333328247070312 * 16 = 5.333251953
```

What should I do to get the same results as a regular calculator in Swift?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inexact. [What every computer programmer should know about floating point](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html).

Comment: Thanks every one a found the solution i used Double type instead Float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "regular calculator" seems wrong or weird in result printing, so, you should not rely on it. I've rechecked your calculation in Python3 which is known to calculate all in binary64 double and print the most exact decimal form:

```
>>> 0.333328247070312 * 16
5.333251953124992
```

it's even more detailed (by one digit) than Swift output. Your output also can't be verified as binary32 calculation, because the latter has ~7 correct decimal digits, and usually isn't printed with more digits. What this calculator is? I'd suppose some Pascal-based tool due to its custom 6-byte float.

Try to ask your calculator to print the most detailed form. If it fails, throw it away and use a most exact tool to verify, or, if your task is really to get the same result, figure out more details about its processing.